# Lumen Authorization - Call to a member function parameter() on array

Tags: php, lumen

Trying to authorize a user to update a post if the user id and the post user_id matches. I have a custom callback for authorization in the `AuthServiceProvider` which checks for `'Authorization'` header, which is an API key in the `boot()` function.

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
            if($request->header('Authorization')) {
                $user = $this->getUserFromAuthorizationHeader($request);

                if (!empty($user)) {
                    $request->request->add(['userid' => $user->id]);
                }

                return $user;
            }
        });
```

The function `getUserFromAuthorizationHeader` gets a `Request $request` parameter and extracts the `Authorization` header, which is an api key, and then returns a `User` object.

I defined a gate `update-post` which checks the user that is returned from the callback and the post passed when calling the gate `update-post` from a controller.

```
Gate::define('update-post', function($user, $post){
            Log::info($user);
            return $user->id == $post->user_id;
        });
```

The way I am calling the Gate in my `PostController` is by the following

```
...
$user = $this->getUserFromRequest($request);
        if(Gate::denies('update-post', $post)) {
            return response("Unauthorized.", 401);
        }
...
```

I logged - `using Log:: info()` - the `$user` and `$post` variables in my Gate and I can successfully see the correct user and post objects being passed, but I get the error `Call to a member function parameter() on array` and I can't understand why exactly I am getting it.

Comment: where is `parameter()` in your question I can't find it

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid I never call `parameter()` anywhere in my code.

Comment: looks like `$user` and `$post` is of array type no?

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid yes, I believe so. If I log $user I'd get `{"id":1,"name":"Admin","email":"admin@example.com", "api_key":"dHBkZFp1M1lvN2pSanRHM0RpU3VTNWVRcDJUTFY0NndVa0ZLdTduUw=="}` and the `$post` would log the same type of arra. But even though I'm extracting from both arrays the value of the key I want, which is the `id` of both the user and the post.

Comment: When you get that `Call to a member function` error, it should also specify the file and line number along with the call stack - can you share that snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to convert into collection before comparing if you are getting the array like this

```
$post = collect($post);
$user = collect($user);
Gate::define('update-post', function($user, $post){
            Log::info($user);
            return $user->id == $post->user_id;
        });
```

[Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) Reference